# Caliburn Micro Model executes, window doesn't show up

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

I'm encountering difficulties using `Caliburn.Micro` in my wpf project: any view's model's code is executed, but the window never shows up. Thus, the `OnViewLoaded` can show a MessageBox while the window remains invisible.

This is my bootstrapper:

```
public class Bootstrapper : BootstrapperBase
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     IoC container for dependency injection
    /// </summary>
    private readonly SimpleContainer _container = new SimpleContainer();

    private static Bootstrapper bootstrapper;
    public Bootstrapper()
    {
        Initialize();

        ConventionManager.AddElementConvention<PasswordBox>(ZBMS.PasswordHelper.BoundPasswordBox.BoundPasswordProperty, "Password",
            "PasswordChanged");
    }

    protected override void Configure()
    {
        //Callback for redirecting pressed keys to the corresponding viewmodel
        MessageBinder.SpecialValues.Add("$pressedkey", (context) =>
        {
            var keyArgs = context.EventArgs as KeyEventArgs;
                return keyArgs?.Key;
        });


        // reset settings when debugger is attached (vs obviously) 

        if (Debugger.IsAttached)
            Settings.Default.Reset();

        _container.Singleton<IEventAggregator, EventAggregator>();
        _container.Singleton<IWindowManager, WindowManager>();

        //_Container.Singleton<ISettingsManager, NETSettingsManager>();
        _container.PerRequest<LoadingScreenViewModel>();
    }

    protected override void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
        => DisplayRootViewFor<LoadingScreenViewModel>();

    protected override object GetInstance(Type service, string key)
    {
        var instance = _container.GetInstance(service, key);
        if (instance != null)
        return instance;
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Could not locate any instances.");
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<Assembly> SelectAssemblies()
    {
        return new[]
        {
            Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
        };
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<object> GetAllInstances(Type service)
    {
        return _container.GetAllInstances(service);
    }

    protected override void BuildUp(object instance)
    {
        _container.BuildUp(instance);
    }
}
```

Comment: I found out that in App.xaml, `<local:Bootstrapper x:Key="Bootstrapper"/>` throws an error (however, I could compile the whole thing), "An item with the same key has already been added". In another project of mine, caliburn works fine and this error doesn't come up.

Comment: On which line is the error thrown?